# KonoSuba Manga chapter 100 in the LN?

Tags: konosuba

Recently, i readed the chapter 100 of the KonoSuba Manga, and since i'm a huge fan of the series i wanted to start reading the LN right away. So, dos anyone knows in which chapter can I continue the story where the manga left off?

Comment: Not an answer, but according to [this](https://deaino-onayami.com/konosuba-novel-manga-dotti/), manga vol 8 corresponds to novel vol 6. Assuming 10-11 chapters per manga vol, chapter 100+ should be roughly equivalent to novel vol 7 or 8. (Total volumes are 16 for manga and 17 for novels).